# Trackpad pinch causes `wheel` JS event with `ctrlKey` true, how to tell if the user is holding Ctrl?

Tags: javascript, mouseevent, trackpad

As described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68808218/how-to-capture-pinch-zoom-gestures-from-the-trackpad-in-a-desktop-browser-and-p), the browser fires a [`wheel` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/wheel_event) with the [`ctrlKey` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/ctrlKey) set to `true` when using a multitouch pinch gesture with a laptop trackpad (not a touch screen).

I need to detect when this happens versus when the user is actually scrolling while holding down the Control key so my code can handle them separately. Since the state of `ctrlKey` is "lying", is there another way to distinguish between the two situations?

The only thing that comes to mind is tracking the up and down state of the Control key within the web page, but that is prone to getting stuck in the wrong state if the up or down events occur outside the focused browser window.

Comment: Not a solution to my problem, but related reading that I found valuable: https://danburzo.ro/dom-gestures/

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly are you trying to distinguish? "_actually scrolling while holding down the Control key_", does "_actually scrolling_" here mean a real scroll (a page/element is really scrolled), or do you need to distinguish CTRL + scroll gesture and CTRL + drag on scrollbar from zoom?

Comment: @Teemu I mean using either the physical wheel on a mouse, or a two-finger scroll gesture on a laptop trackpad. I'm not referring to moving content on the page by means of scrolling, nor dragging a scrollbar. I have my own renderer so neither DOM content nor scrollbars are relevant, but the physical input is what I'm looking for.

Comment: I made some investigations, and found a ton of cross-browser issues. [This fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0bpw492y/) works on Firefox, but not on Chromium browsers. The snippet relies on trackpad passing `WheelEvent.deltaX/Y` in decimals, but in Chromium they seem to be integers. Also, CTRL + pinch zoom is not firing `wheel` event in FF, and the snippet fails to detect CTRL + trackpad scroll.

Comment: @Keavon dd you ever find a solution to your problem?

Comment: I think one workaround would be look at keydown / keyup if track if the ctrl is actually pressed or not.

Comment: Never found a solution, but your suggestion to track up and down events was going to be my eventual plan. (It's just tricky to do it as robustly as possible.)